# How to set the width of an element in HTML from a "variable"

Tags: php, html

I want to set the width of a progress bar I have, but since HTML doesn't really have variables I tried this:

```
<span class="bar" style="width:<?php echo $goal_percent . '%'; ?>"></div>
```

I know it's wrong, I just don't know how I would do something like this?

Edit: Here is more of the code I'm using:

```
                            <?php
                            $goal_percent = $goal / 100;
                            $goal_percent = $goal * 100;
                            if($goal_percent == 0)
                            {
                            $goal_percent = 1;
                            }
                            $goal_percent = 50;
                            ?>

                            <span class="progress progress-success progress-striped active" style="margin-bottom: 9px;">
                        <span class="bar" style="width:<?php echo $goal_percent; ?>%"></span>
```

I'm setting goal percent to 50 after just for testing just in case something else was going wrong with the math. Still not working.

Comment: yep, I don't know what you're trying but jQuery will probably do that for you and it shouldn't be hard.

Comment: Is your $global_Percent initialized?

Comment: You should end the span with a span not a div, perhaps typo?

Comment: Does it work? Was it in the typo?

Comment: @Pier-alexandreBouchard I don't think it was the typo. Edited more code in. Still not working.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Yes was a typo, fixed it but still same issue.

Comment: @j08691 I don't think I would want to use it for this but I added more code maybe that will help you decide if it would be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code Will work. I just test it:

```
<html>
    <head><title>Test</title></head>
    <body>
        <?php $goal_percent=50; ?>
        <div class="bar" style="width:<?php echo $goal_percent; ?>%"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Interesting it's working now! I switched it to use the div tags like you have shown rather then span. Works now!

Answer (score 1):

As long as `$goal_percent` is a valid int/float variable.  Like @LawrenceCherone mentioned:

```
<span class="bar" style="width:<?php echo $goal_percent; ?>%"></span>
```